# Binding to an auto-updating object?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, xaml

Is there an object or interface I can use to make an auto-updating object, and have those updates filter through to the UI in WPF?

Basically I'm looking for something like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource myClass}, Path=DataObject}" />

public class MyClass
{
    public AutoUpdatingObject DataObject { get; set; }
}

public class AutoUpdatingObject: ???
{
    ???
}
```

No I can't make MyClass implement INotifyPropertyChanged. I need the AutoUpdatingObject class to be able to notify WPF of changes.

Comment: Why can't you implement INotifyPropertyChanged ?

Comment: Ugh, you might be in a pickle here, mate. If you can change the XAML, try PriorityBinding w/ one binding to the MyClass and one to a dummy class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged and know when AutoUpdatingObject is done. not sure PriorityBinding will pick these notifications though.

Comment: This will be for a library, where the users of the library will be implementing the MyClass object. I can implement INotifyPropertyChanged on AutoUpdatingObject if that'll work.

Answer (score 1):

Implementing INotifyPropertyChanged is not the only way to update bindings, you can also use events without implementing an interface.

[Using a CLR Class as the Binding Source Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743643.aspx#classes)

> If you do not implement
>   INotifyPropertyChanged, then you must
>   arrange for your own notification
>   system to make sure that the data used
>   in a binding stays current. You can
>   provide change notifications by
>   supporting the PropertyChanged pattern
>   for each property that you want change
>   notifications for. To support this
>   pattern, you define a
>   PropertyNameChanged event for each
>   property, where PropertyName is the
>   name of the property. You raise the
>   event every time the property changes.

In your case MyClass would look like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private AutoUpdatingObject dataObject;
    public AutoUpdatingObject DataObject
    {
        get { return dataObject; }
        set { dataObject = value; DataObjectChanged(this, new EventArgs()); }
    }

    public event EventHandler DataObjectChanged = delegate { };
}
```